# IE: remove "quick infos" button?

Tags: internet-explorer, button, quickinfo

I need to remove the "quick infos" button in Internet Explorer because I have a drag and drop javascript function and after every drag action the stupid button appears.

Is there a way to remove this button? And can I do that for my users via javascript in my asp.net application?

**The annoying button:**

http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/p/k/q2UCr297/dbbd0f45.png

*If the image is not shown, try this link:* http://www.suckmypic.net/27082/dbbd0f45.png

Comment: what button? the image is not showing...

Comment: added alternative link to view the image

Comment: you can't disable this from javascript or programatically... you need to disable it from the IE settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable IE8 Accelerators And Stop The Small Blue Icon Pop Ups(IE 8):

- Open Internet Explorer 8 Options: Click on Tools in the top
  navigation bar and select Options from the drop down to open IE8
  Options.
- Open IE8 Advanced Options: From the Internet Options configuration
  window displayed in the above image click the Advanced tab which will
  display the Advanced Internet Options.
- Disabled IE8 Accelerators: Scroll down to “Display Accelerator button
  on selection” which is located under the Browsing section of the
  Advanced Options configuration window. Remove the check from the the
  box next to the “Display Accelerator button on selection” option.
  Click the Apply button followed by the OK button to close the
  Internet Options configuration window.
- Verify IE8 Accelerator Button Disabled: Now highlight text on a web
  page to make sure that the Accelerator button no longer displays.

Now you don’t have to worry about accidently clicking the Accelerator button every time you highlight text on a web page. If you find that Accelerators might be beneficial to you then you can add the check back to the “Display Accelerator button on select” in Advanced Internet Options.